# Hadoop grep search output - job counters

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am currently running a hadoop cluster with 6 nodes 1 master and 5 slaves. The master does not have any tasktracker/datanode running in it. I am running grep and trying to read the output logs. I am able to find the grep sort output (The output directory I provided) but I am not able to find the temporary folder created during grep search. Can someone please tell me how to get grep search results and the logs associated with it. I am looking for the log containing the various counters. Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you !

Sethu

Comment: Please specify, do you want to find application logs from the job, or you want to find job counters? (or both..)

Comment: I need both ! We modified hadoop to print multiple metrics to that log (Along with job counter). I would like to take a look at the multiple counters for grep search. But unfortunately it gets deleted after starting the grep sort phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the grep program in the examples folder to suit my needs. It solved my issue.